# The most efficient way to convert long[] to Long[]

Tags: java, casting

What is the most efficient way to convert an array of `long` type values - `long[]` to an array of `Long` objects - `Long[]` ?

Comment: It's never going to be very efficient...

Comment: It potentially creates a new object for every element which is going to be expensive.  This best thing is avoid needing to do this in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dumb way.

```
Long[] result = new Long[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  result[i] = array[i];
}
```

There's no other, better way.  Sorry.

(Why do you need to do this, may I ask?  There may be better alternatives if we knew why you needed these boxed.)

Comment: Do not apologize, it's not your fault. ;-)) Thanks !

Comment: I have an util generics method, so I can't work with basic types.

Comment: hsz, I think the question was more in the way of suggesting you not to convert at the array level, but perhaps convert directly from primitive `long`s at the use site.

Comment: There is a better way - use at least for each cycle in order to check array bounds only once :-)

Comment: @malejpavouk That sounds like micro-optimization that will happen anyway -- and it only manages to eliminate one of the two bounds checks.

Comment: The JIT is pretty smart at optimizing away bounds checks, and for a simple, straightforward loop like this?  I'd be pretty shocked if the JIT couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You should try Apache commons -  [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html).

```
static java.lang.Long[] toObject(long[] array)
```

Comment: @LouisWasserman Checked, your solution in fact **beats** `ArrayUtils` because they instantiate `Long`s unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

With out `iteration` this is not possible . You will have explicitly Wrap them in `Long` using `autoboxing`